# Support of Active Directory Graph Api without Azure application

Tags: azure, active-directory, ldap, windows-server-2008, azure-active-directory

I developed a native app which sync Active directory using Azure graph api and the AD data is consumed by web and mobile apps. It is working fine.

But now my client wants to use same app for AD syncing purpose in another server which is may be windows server 2008 or below. Which is not support Azure platform as per clients technical team.

My question is that is there any way can I use same app without using azure platform or can is there any way can I use AD graph API in windows server? In else case I will need to do development from the scratch using LDAP.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

Currently, there is no way to "deploy" neither the Azure AD Graph nor the Microsoft Graph such that you can leverage the same code for on prem and the cloud. As you've indicated, you will need to either have two apps or have a fork in your code to call the Graph when running with Azure AD and do LDAP queries when running purely on prem.